# Can't get this controller method to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to toggle user as admin with a link click. I changed the code based on recommendations but it's still not working.

Controller:

```
def toggle_admin
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.is_admin == true
      @user.is_admin = false
    else
      @user.is_admin = true
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @users }
    end
end
```

Stement from view that calls method:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Toggle Admin', :controller => :users, :method => :toggle_admin, :id => user.id, data: { confirm: 'Toggle Admin?' } %></td>
```

Route:

```
match 'users/:id/toggle_admin' => 'user#toggle_admin'
```

Does anybody see my mistake?  Thanks.

I think my routing might be the problem.  Look at how the logs only show retrieval of all Users and then the User that matches the id:

```
Started GET "/users?data%5Bconfirm%5D=Toggle+Admin%3F&id=1&method=toggle_admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-13 12:16:25 -0400
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"data"=>{"confirm"=>"Toggle Admin?"}, "id"=>"1", "method"=>"toggle_admin"}
  User Load (36.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
  User Load (71.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (78.2ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a

```
@user.save
```

somewhere in there.

Besides, the entire `if` block could probably be replaced by

```
@user.is_admin = !@user.is_admin
```

Comment: That's actually not working. Started GET "/users?data%5Bconfirm%5D=Toggle+Admin%3F&id=1&method=toggle_admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-13 12:10:38 -0400
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"data"=>{"confirm"=>"Toggle Admin?"}, "id"=>"1", "method"=>"toggle_admin"}
  User Load (38.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
  User Load (36.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]

Answer (score 1):

try as follow;

```
def toggle_admin
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.is_admin == true
      @user.is_admin = false
    else
      @user.is_admin = true
    end

    @user.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @users }
    end
end
```

or you can also do use `update_attributes` as follow

```
@user.update_attributes(is_admin: true)
```

Comment: I thought that would work but no luck.  It seems to just be getting the record from the db and doing nothing with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toggle](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/toggle) to accomplish this, if `is_admin` is a boolean value:

```
def toggle_admin
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.toggle :is_admin
  @user.save

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @users }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a defect in the controller call.  It should be:

`<%= link_to 'Toggle Admin', { :controller => :users, :action => :toggle_admin, :id => user.id} %>`